# Deploying applications using marathon using GIT Repository

Tags: git, mesos, marathon

Is it possible to deploy applications from marathon using git repository for source code and bash scripts to run instances? If yes how to handle authentication in such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. See the docs around [Authentication HTTP API Endpoint](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/security/auth-api/) along with `curl` or `http`. Alternatively you can use [dploy](http://dploy.sh/) which comes with a push-to-deploy function.